# Connecting to MongoDB in Production With Mongoose

Tags: reactjs, linux, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a ReactJS app built out on my development machine and connect to a MongoDB database using Mongoose via http://127.0.0.1:5000.  I used express and mongoose on my dev machine which is working fine.  I pushed my code to my production server (Ubuntu), however I do not know how connect to MongoDB.  I've tried running the same server file over port 5000, just to see if I could connect.  No luck.  I've also tried using my domain name instead of localhost in production to see if that would work...No luck.  I could use some advice on how to make my app work and connect to MongoDB in a production environment.  Thanks.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const routes = require('./routes/api');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// CONNECT TO THE MONGODB DATABASE USING MONGOOSE
const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri);

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})

app.use('/api', routes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Default port for MongoDB is 27017 and it is not HTTP. Thus, this is not a connection to a Mongo database.

Comment: Please provide your code an error message.

Comment: There is no error message, but if I run that server in production and try to go to my app in the browser, I see a CORS error (in console) because it's trying to connect through localhost.

Comment: I resolved this by changing my port in production to 3000 and was able to keep my local dev machine at 5000 - RESOLVED.